# I can't understand why my program is asking for pointer in the index of an array

Tags: arrays, c

I am writing a code to find the intersection of 2 arrays. With my `i` and `j` iterators, the IDE is asking me to convert them to pointers or something. I'm specifically getting a pointer-to-object error.

Also I can't really wrap my head around when and how to use pointers. I know what they are (kind of) but I don't understand when to use them.

```
void arrIntersect(int fArr, int sArr, int fArrElem, int sArrElem)
{
    int i, j, k;

    int largeArrElem = (fArrElem > sArrElem)?fArrElem:sArrElem;
    int unionArr[largeArrElem];

    for (i = 0; i < largeArrElem; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < largeArrElem; j++)
        {
            if (fArr[i] == sArr[j]) //Here the i and j say pointer to object//
            {
                for (k = 0; k < largeArrElem; k++)
                {
                    unionArr[k] = fArr[i]; //Here the i says pointer to object//
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    for (k = 0; k < largeArrElem; k++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", unionArr[k]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `fArr` and `sArr` aren't pointers (`int *`) so `fArr[i]` and `sArr[i]` won't work.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Can you please tell why do they need to be pointers? I've searched near and far about pointers but I can't still understand them.

Comment: Because bracket notation as an index doesn't make any sense with an integer.  `a[n]` is semantically equivalent to `*(a + n)`.  That is, it is dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: Perhaps you just want `void arrIntersect(int fArr[], int sArr[], int fArrElem, int sArrElem)`

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you're calling `arrIntersect`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits here- `

arrIntersect(fArr, sArr, fArrElem, sArrElem); //Here fArr and sArr are arrays, the other 2 are their sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your intersection function is not right.You must decrise the size of largArrElem and also you have to decrise the size of j.Now for your problem with the arrays did you try to to create them dynamicaly with malloc ?Also if you did that i thing you must add " * " in parametres
like:

```
void arrIntersect(int *fArr, int *sArr, int fArrElem, int sArrElem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it, there will be no error -

```
void arrIntersect(int fArr[], int sArr[], int fArrElem, int sArrElem)
```